# Can I align a CSS3 comment-bubble properly inside a title?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a comment bubble at the end of a heading, but I can't find away to move it upwards a bit.

See the example in the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/3yn9r/

The only way I succeeded placing it at the end of the heading was to put in inside the h1 (not really a good way for structuring). Even so, I can't move it up to align properly (the bottom triangle on the base of the text). Negative margin-top doesn't work.

Any clue if this can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/3yn9r/2/. Give `top` instead of `margin-top`

Comment: who give me a downvote please explain me the reason thanks :)

Comment: what's with the -1? Greedz, if that was you, if you're that quick to downvote, you're not going to get any help.

Comment: Anyways, my suggestion was going to be the same as sandeep's but he beat me to it.

Comment: Wasn't me, and that was the solution. I thought the top property was something relative to absolute positioning, need to read up on this. Anyway, many thanks! Marking as solution after the 3m limit.